# flutter web: rangeerror: value not in range: 12

Tags: flutter, web, stream-builder

I want to show a user's firestore information using streambuilder, but can't. The following is my code, but when I build this page I get a red screen and an error message `Value not in range: 12 The relevant error-causing widget was StreamBuilder<Userbio>` on my debug console. I don't know what is wrong. Would somebody help me?

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final clientbios = Provider.of<List<Clientbio>>(context) ?? [];
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: clientbios.length + 1,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return StreamBuilder<Userbio>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
                .doc(uid).snapshots()
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          Userbio userbio = snapshot.data;
            return Card(
              child: Text('${userbio.name})
              );});
      } else {
        return ClientbioTile(clientbio: clientbios[index - 1]);
      }
    });
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing: `clientbios.length + 1` as `itemCount`.
You should remove the `+ 1` and have only `clientbios.length`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The reason I wrote that way is that I want to show `clientbios` lists under `userbio` info. So total lengths of the list must be `clientbios.length + 1` including `userbio` info.